# How to force TCP packets for testing DNS?

Tags: dns, bind, dig

DNS uses UDP packets normally. However when the response is larger than a certain size, it switches to TCP.

It would be very useful if we can specify TCP/UDP when running DNS query commands with DIG or NSLOOKUP for example.

Is there a way to do this with DIG?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With dig you can use `+tcp`.

`man dig` says:

```
+[no]tcp
Use [do not use] TCP when querying name servers. The default behavior is to use UDP unless a type any or ixfr=N query is requested, in which case the default is TCP. AXFR queries always use TCP.

+[no]vc
Use [do not use] TCP when querying name servers. This alternate syntax to +[no]tcp is provided for backwards compatibility. The "vc" stands for "virtual circuit".
```

So both `+tcp` and `+vc` does what you want, but `+tcp` is a bit more clear in what you're trying to do.

Using dig myself and tracing the traffic with Wireshark I see that `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` uses UDP and `dig google.com @8.8.8.8 +tcp` uses TCP.

Answer (score 7):

The old tools call this "virtual circuit" (vc) mode:

```
dig google.com @8.8.8.8 +vc

nslookup -vc google.com 8.8.8.8
```

Windows nslookup (interactive mode):

```
nslookup> set vc
```